# fopen() seems not work when I create a daemon process

Tags: c, process, fopen, daemon

Here is my main source code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    [...]

    if (become_daemon(0) == -1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (main_loop == LOOP_CONTINUE) {
        [...]

        if (log_data(date_temp, data_processed) < 0) {
            [...]
        } else {
            [...]
        }
        sleep(measure_rate);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Here my functions definitions:

```
int become_daemon(int flags) {
    int maxfd, fd;

    switch (fork()) {
      case -1:
        return -1;
      case 0:
        break;
      default:
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (setsid() == -1)
        return -1;

    switch (fork()) {
      case -1:
        return -1;
      case 0:
        break;
      default:
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if (!(flags & BD_NO_MASK0))
        umask(0);

    if (!(flags & BD_NO_CHDIR))
        chdir("/");

    if (!(flags & BD_NO_CLOSE_FILE)) {
        maxfd = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX);
        if (maxfd == -1)
            maxfd = BD_MAX_CLOSE;

        for (fd = 0; fd < maxfd; fd++)
            close(fd);
    }

    if (!(flags & BD_NO_REOPEN_STD_FDS)) {
        close(STDIN_FILENO);

        fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);

        if (fd != STDIN_FILENO)
            return -1;
        if (dup2(STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO)
            return -1;
        if (dup2(STDIN_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO) != STDERR_FILENO)
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int log_data(char *date, double array_data[DATA_NUM]) {
    FILE *file;

    if ((file = fopen(DATALOG_FILE, "a")) == NULL)
        return -1;

    fprintf(file, "%s ; %.2f ; %.2f ; %.2f ; %.2f ; %.2f ; %.2f\n",
            date, array_data[0], array_data[1], array_data[2],
            array_data[3], array_data[4], array_data[5]);

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is my problem:

when I compile my code with the `become_daemon()` function active and then I  execute the program, the file `DATALOG_FILE` (it's a define for `"xxxxxx.txt"`) it's not created. If I compile without the `become_daemon()` function call, the program works fine and the file is created.

I even noticed that if I add the line

```
sudo /my/folder/program
```

in the `rc.local` to run it at the boot, it starts like I want but, even in these case, it does not create the file DATALOG_FILE.

I'm newbie with daemon process so can anyone tell me the cause of this behavior?

Comment: become_daemon changes the cwd to `/`, may this be the issue? Since the DATALOG_FILE seems  to be a relative path...

Comment: Surely you can narrow down the problem further than the file is not created. *Why* is it not created? Does the `fopen` call fail? Does the `become_daemon` call fail? Something else? Once you find which call fails then you can get the `errno` to further narrow down the cause. It should be easy to dig a bit further before seeking help.

Comment: The `chdir("/")` in `become_daemon()` means that the daemon tries (and probably fails) to create the file in the root directory.  Specify the absolute pathname of the file, not a relative name.  Or decide whether the `chdir("/")` is sensible.  There are reasons to do it; sometimes, there are reasons to change directory to some other location, and sometimes (though less often) there are reasons not to change directory at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ctx mentioned in his comment, the function `become_daemon` may change the current directory to `/`.  If `DATALOG_FILE` is a relative filename, such as `"xxxxxx.txt"` as you write in the question, the daemon will fail to create it in the system root directory, unless it has root privileges.

Either do not change the current directory by passing `BD_NO_CHDIR` as an argument to `become_daemon` or make `DATALOG_FILE` an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it solved my problem relative to daemon process. But what about `rc.local`? If I add the line `/my/folder/program` to start it at boot, it seems to change again the directory in `/`. Can you explain me why?

Comment: @thoraz: it does not *change the directory* then, it starts with `/` as its current directory.